# Verificating google oauth without answer

Tags: google-oauth

I am trying to verify integration of my app with google sheets but even after filling and sending the verification form multiple times I got no response from google which is strange because before when I was verifying google drive api integration I got response even when I got something wrong. Is there a way to contact google about this or check the status of verification ?

Answer (score 0):

[Oauth2 client verification](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification)

> Starting July 18, 2017, Google OAuth clients that request certain sensitive OAuth scopes will be subject to review by Google.
>
> This change applies to Google OAuth web clients, including those used by all Apps Script projects. By [verifying your app with Google](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification#requesting_verification), you can remove the unverified app screen from your authorization flow and give your users confidence that your app is non-malicious.
>
> Most verification requests receive a response within 24 to 72 hours. When verification of your OAuth client is confirmed, your app is verified.

I would wait a week and then try again.  You should get an email from Google if you don't qualify for one reason or another.   You could also check what scopes you are requesting.  Only request the ones you really need.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Well we tried to fill the form many times during the last few month but we got no response... We already got one integration with google drive authorized, after that we implemented google sheets and in google console created new project for It. Is that correct ? should every new integration has its own project even if it's for the same app ?

Comment: If you create a new application you will need to make a new project.   If its the same application you should not be making a new project.

Comment: That will be the problem then. But We actually tried that back in september, we had google drive which was already verified and google sheets under the same project and we tried to verify google sheets. We got response that we are trying to change scope and that `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` should do it. So basically instead of verifing our new integration they tought we want to change our existing integration scopes.

Comment: I am looking at the verification form and there is client ID field, which means each oauth2 is separate, then I don't understand why they tought we want to change scope for client_id that is not even verified yet.

Comment: You should only change your client id if you are creating a new application.  Each application should have its own deditcated client id.    If you add scopes to the client and they need to verify it you will loose the verify tag and have to apply again.

Comment: So, If I have web myApp I first want to make google drive connection then I need to create new project and new Oauth client_id. I verify this and then I decide to connect googleSheets to web myApp, so should I just add new Authorized redirect URIs to my existing Oauth client_id ? This will result in both of them having same login credentials or no ?

Comment: If its the same web app myApp you should just edit the client to enable  sheets API and Drive API.   You wont need to apply for verification again as the sheets scopes are the same as the drive scopes you have already been verified.   If you create a new client your users are going to have ot login again which is silly really if its the same app

Comment: Now I see, I used `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets` scope which was not needed, It is working also with `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` . Also you are right with the login now when they have same scopes. Thank you